# Reactjs | react-router-dom | Multiple files ..module.scss | style problem

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-router-dom

I have a problem with my **module.scss** files.

I use react-router-dom for multiple pages.

I have different style on **"body"** tag for every pages, but the styles overlap..

How can I stylize the body tag for each page **without overlapping styles**?

Or how can I make sure that when react-router-dom changes the page it doesn't load the style used on another page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general way an using only SASS and react-router-dom, there is no builtin way to do it.

Alternatively, you could implement your own way to do so. But consider using a React component to style rather than body because body shouldn't be modified directly to prevent style conflicting.

Said that, for each page that `react-router-dom` mounts, you can create a arbitrary class name to use:

```css
.home {
  background: red;
}

.about {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

Then you add that class to the body when components mounts and remove when component unmount.

```js
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> / <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("home");
    return () => document.body.classList.remove("home");
  }, []);
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("about");
    return () => document.body.classList.remove("about");
  }, []);
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}
```

`useEffect` body is called when your component is mounted. It will never be executed again if you provide an empty array as second argument. [More details here](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The returned function will be executed only when your component is umounted.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.body.classList.add("home");
  return () => document.body.classList.remove("home");
}, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-frog-88yel

To promote code reusability you also can create a reusable custom hook and isolate the duplicated behavior:

```js
const useBodyClassName = (className) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add(className);
    return () => document.body.classList.remove(className);
  }, []);
};
```